# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Adding User Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, reference, null

The thing is I am new in Entity Framework and I must be missing something small.

Anyways, I have three tables and I am getting the error adding the user:

- Users
- Logins
- ShippingProfiles

Relationship:

- 1 to 1 : Users - logins
- 1 to many: Users - ShippingProfiles

My code behind:

```
 User user = new User();
 user.AddUser(user, firstNameInput.Text, lastNameInput.Text, emailList, bdayInput.Text, emailInput.Text);
```

My context:

```
public class DBCS : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShippingProfile> ShippingProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(user => user.ShippingProfiles)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }

}
```

So I am trying to add the user and I am getting the error

```
[Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EmailList { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ShippingProfile> ShippingProfiles { get; set; }

    public void AddUser(User user,string firstNameInput, string lastNameInput, int emailListInput, string bdayInput, string emailInput)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DBCS())
        {
            user.Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(bdayInput);
            user.Email = emailInput;
            user.EmailList = Convert.ToInt32(emailListInput);
            user.FirstName = firstNameInput;
            user.LastName = lastNameInput;

            dbContext.Users.Add(user); // Error Here
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }   
    }
```

This can be a stupid question, but I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Signature of AddUser have 5 parameters. When using this method you are passing 6 parameters.
2. Object reference error is coming from implementation of AddUser method, where 'user'' is not initialized and added into  dbContext.Users.

Comment: 1-  Yeah I saw that later on. 2- I want to fix this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Change signature of AddUser to accept only 1 parameter, User. Before calling AddUser, create User object and filled it's property by values from text-boxes. Have only below code in AddUser method.                     public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DBCS())
        {
            dbContext.Users.Add(user);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }   
    }

Comment: Sorry, somehow formatting is not getting auto-corrected.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still get the same error with these changes